# How to display it to span

Tags: javascript, html, function, frontend

I'd to ask how to display the output to span. i always get blank and whenever i alert the txtNumber i get "object html span element " on the alert code.

```
<span id="displayQty"> number </span>
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="+" onclick="add2()" />
```

Script

```
function add2() {
    var txtNumber = document.getElementById("displayQty");
    var number = parseInt(txtNumber.value) + 1;
    txtNumber.value = number;
    alert(displayQty.value);
}
```

Comment: Change `txtNumber.value = number;` to `txtNumber.innerHTML = number;` Check [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/s36gkt8s/)

Comment: i get a Nan!   @Tushar

Comment: Tushar's demo works fine.

Comment: thats a code only answer. help me understand why. @NaguibIhab

Comment: @Lemon Check [**Demo with Code Explained**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/s4qdcxqb/)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention two things.

1) When you use `txtNumber.value,`it access the value attribute of the element associated with txtNumber variable. But there is no value attribute. If you want to access what is written in between the span tag (here it is a string 'number'), you should use `txtNumber.innerHTML.`This returns all the HTML stuffs inside your span.

2) The next thing, you cannot just add a string to a number, a object to a number. I can see that you have used `parseInt` `but it is used to convert a string with integer signature to integer datatype. ("5" converts to 5).

**Well try this-**

```
<html>
<body


<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="+" onclick="add2()" />
<span id="displayQty">1</span>

<script>

function add2() {
    var txtNumber = document.getElementById("displayQty");
    var number = parseInt(txtNumber.innerHTML.trim()) + 1;
    txtNumber.innerHTML = number;

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

if you replace `var number = parseInt(txtNumber.innerHTML.trim()) + 1;` by

```
var number = txtNumber.innerHTML  + 1;
```

it will add the two numbers as strings and the output is 11 . But replacing it with `var number = txtNumber.innerHTML - (-1)` does the trick and adds them as integers.

Comment: Have you used the complete code? Remember inside the span tag, there should be integers only.  In your case it was 'number' before. Number + 1 is meaningless. Just like banana + apple is meaningless in context of addition